# VLookup error when searching with numbers and text

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am new to VBA and am trying to recode a program that already exists, with the intention of optimizing it and adding new features. The program takes a scanner input (though I am just manually entering in the numbers at the moment), which then records and categorizes the type of item that is taken out. It is then put in a log for reference later. Here is the first Userform that takes the scanned input:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim barcode As Long, emptyRow As Long, testHold As Long
Set TempHold = Worksheets("TempHold")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(TempHold.Range("D2:D25"), TextBox1.Value) = 1 Then
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then

CartTypeMenu.Show

barcode = TextBox1.Value
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(barcode, TempHold.Range("D2:E25"), 2, True)
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = barcode
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn")
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = CartTypeMenu.ComboBox1.Value

TextBox1.Value = ""

Else

    testHold = TextBox1.Value
    Call boxTest(testHold)

End If

End If

End Sub
```

I have two tables in a separate sheet (TempHold) that have the scanned input corresponding to a number, and a number corresponding to a name. The row in the final log would basically be the number of the scanned input (as they are labeled by number), the scanned input, the time (which works properly), the type and then the name.

The problem I run into is when I search VLookup for the name to put into the next cell in the log row; getting the name from a number. It only looks for the name if it is actively in the log (it is cleared once tasks are completed). I have tried changing the numbers to strings, and vice versa, but I can't get it to work. Here is the problematic module:

```
Sub boxTest(testHold As Long)

Dim offsetValue As Long, myValue As Variant

Set ws = Worksheets("Log")
Set sheetLookup = Worksheets("TempHold")

offsetValue = Application.Match(testHold, ws.Range("B2:B8"), 0)

myValue = InputBox("Enter your number")

ws.Range("E" & offsetValue).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myValue, sheetLookup.Range("A2:B9"), 1, True)

End Sub
```

VLookup keeps giving the error that it can't find the WorksheetFunction in this module.

Comment: Is A2:A9 sorted ascending? It has to be with True in vlookup.

Comment: I have the names in that column. I turned it to False and still got the same error (the names are of number datatype).

Comment: Didn't ask what the nature of the cell values was; just wanted to know if A2:A9 was sorted ascending **because it has to be sorted ascending to use True**.

Comment: My apologies. Didn't know if that information mattered or not. Thanks for the reply. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Do you want `"E" & offsetValue` to be 1 row above the match to testHold? Match is returning the *position within* B**2**:B8 but you are using it like it was B**1**:B8.

Comment: No, I want it to be on the same row. I fixed the error. Thank you.